# riot.js how to custom a DOM event handler

Tags: events, riot.js

where could i custom a event handler to bound. These events are very common like tap, taphold, swipeleft, swiperight

---

```
<div ontap="{onTap}" ontaphold="{onTapHold}" onswipeleft="{onSwipeLeft}" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the "normal" events, a useful bunch are listed here: https://martinmuzatko.github.io/riot-cheatsheet/#global-events